# Models structure in MVC for image processing application with multiple algorithms

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, architecture

I am trying to build a desktop application using python and Qt. The application will process images. There are multiple steps in the processing with each step having different algorithms. Each algorithm can also have varying amounts of parameters that the user should enter. For example there are 3 steps in the pipeline: preprocessing, reconstruction and postprocessing. Each of them have 2 separate algorithms and each algorithm takes in 2-3 parameters.

Since I want to use MVC I thought I would have a processing view, model and a controller. From my understanding the functionalities of the components should be as follows:

- View: The user interface. In this case a PyQt Widget or an application.
- Controller: The brains of the system. Where the logic is and where the decisions are made. Takes in the user actions and updates the model
- Model: Holds information about the state of the application. In my case, what algorithms the user selected and what parameter values they chose. Also the image information (but I want to have a separate visualization subsystem where the image is shown and user can change colormaps etc. For the sake of simplicity we can assume the image is also saved here)

This all makes on paper but things get a little more complicated when I start to implement it. I could not handle in the reconstruction view, the many different parameters and how the model should update them.

I tried to follow this answer: [MVC design with Qt Designer and PyQt / PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698628/mvc-design-with-qt-designer-and-pyqt-pyside). At first my idea was:

- For each step in the pipeline have a model property to hold information about which of the algorithms is selected. Something like this for each of the preprocessing, reconstruction and postprocessing:

```
preprocessor_changed = Signal(str)
@property
def preprocessor(self):
     return self._preprocessor

@preprocessor.setter
def preprocessor(self, value):
     self._preprocessor = value
     self.preprocessor_changed.emit(value)  # The view has a Slot for this signal and updates the dropdown to select the correct preprocessing option
```

- I also needed to hold the parameters for the algorithms. So I added properties again for the 3 different steps of the algorithm. At this stage it got confusing because each of the algorithms have different number of parameters. So in the view I write the parameters into a dictionary and pass the dictionary on to the controller to save them in the model

View:

```
self._ui.preproc_alg1_param1.valueChanged.connect(self.set_fft_params)
self._ui.preproc_alg1_param2.valueChanged.connect(self.set_fft_params)

def set_fft_params(self, value):
        fft_params = {
            "param1": self._ui.preproc_alg1_param1.value(),
            "param2": self._ui.preproc_alg1_param2.value()
        }
        self._controller.set_preproc_params(fft_params)
```

Controller:

```
def set_preproc_params(self, preproc_params):
        self._model.preproc_params = preproc_params
```

Model:

```
@property
def preproc_params(self):
    return self._preproc_params
    
@preproc_params.setter
def preproc_params(self, value):
    self._preproc_params = value
    self.preproc_params_changed.emit(value)  # This causes problems, how will the view know which parameters to update?
```

The issue I am having is that the preprocessing parameters are saved in a dictionary. I want the Slot in the view to recognize that they have been changed and read from the model the updated parameters and write them down. But the view won't know which algorithm the parameters are from. I do not want to have a separate property for each of the algorithms parameters in the model. What would be the best way to handle this case with many algorithms, different number of parameters?

My goal is to have the user select parameters and algorithms from the view, the controller will update the model with the selected values, model will signal to the view that something has changed and the view will be updated. When the user presses a run button the controller will start the processing pipeline (taking the necessary information from the model about what is selected and the image data). Finally the controller will update the model with the resulting image (which will cause the view to be updated and show the new image to the user).

Comment: It's unclear. IIUC, you said you need to distinguish types of processing parameters and you don't want to specify that type information. They contradict. What do you want exactly? You need to provide the example of a desired pattern or interface.

Comment: I want to distinguish the parameters but only for each of the processing steps. it feels unnecessary work to have a property for all possible parameters for all of the processing methods. I was looking for a simpler way to have 1 property for each processing step (not method) that holds the selected parameters.

Comment: Still VERY unclear. You didn't answer my point for your contradicting idea. You introduced another vague terms, processing steps. You mean classes for models or controllers? Provide a concrete example of a desired pattern or interface.